# How do I get the first occurrence of a combination of columns by month in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database that each day loads the contents of some files, which contain the name and the item type of some purchases. I want to mark the first occurrence of each name and item type combination in that calendar month. This is in an Oracle SQL DB table. For example, here is my current table output:

| FILE | NAME | ITEM | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha1 | John | Apple | 012024 |
| Alpha1 | Jane | Orange | 012024 |
| Beta2 | John | Apple | 012024 |
| Beta2 | Jane | Orange | 012024 |
| Alpha2 | John | Apple | 022024 |
| Alpha2 | Jane | Grape | 022024 |

Each unique Name and Item combination appears once per File. I want to update only the first occurrence so that it looks like this (the FIRST column is already part of the table):

| FILE | NAME | ITEM | MONTH | FIRST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha1 | John | Apple | 012024 | Y |
| Alpha1 | Jane | Orange | 012024 | Y |
| Beta2 | John | Apple | 012024 | N |
| Beta2 | Jane | Orange | 012024 | N |
| Alpha2 | John | Apple | 012024 | Y |
| Alpha2 | Jane | Orange | 012024 | Y |

I have tried to combine the relevant columns and list them with the row number, but am not sure how to isolate just the minimum row number, or how to use that in an update statement:

```
SELECT ROWNUM, NAME||ITEM||MONTH AS "RequestID"
FROM alphabeta_table
ORDER BY NAME||ITEM||MONTH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `DATE` column has the `DATE` data-type. *(Note: `DATE` and `FILE` are reserved words so if you want to use them as identifiers then you must use quoted identifiers, which is considered bad practice. A better solution would be to call your columns something else.)*

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function with a `CASE` expression to map the first row to `Y` and other rows to `N`:

```sql
SELECT "FILE",
       name,
       item,
       "DATE",
       CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY name, item, TRUNC("DATE", 'MM')
              ORDER BY "DATE" ASC
            )
       WHEN 1
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END as is_first
FROM   alphabeta_table
ORDER BY
       name,
       item,
       "DATE";
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE alphabeta_table ("FILE", NAME, ITEM, "DATE") AS
SELECT 'Alpha1', 'John', 'Apple',  DATE '2024-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alpha1', 'Jane', 'Orange', DATE '2024-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beta2',  'John', 'Apple',  DATE '2024-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beta2',  'Jane', 'Orange', DATE '2024-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alpha2', 'John', 'Apple',  DATE '2024-02-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alpha2', 'Jane', 'Grape',  DATE '2024-02-20' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FILE | NAME | ITEM | DATE | IS_FIRST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha2 | Jane | Grape | 2024-02-20 00:00:00 | Y |
| Beta2 | Jane | Orange | 2024-01-20 00:00:00 | Y |
| Alpha1 | Jane | Orange | 2024-01-20 00:00:00 | N |
| Alpha1 | John | Apple | 2024-01-20 00:00:00 | Y |
| Beta2 | John | Apple | 2024-01-20 00:00:00 | N |
| Alpha2 | John | Apple | 2024-02-20 00:00:00 | Y |

*Note: There are multiple rows with the same `item`, `name` and `date` combination; in SQL (not just Oracle) the order of result sets is non-deterministic unless `ORDER BY` is used that specifies a total ordering of the results. In this case, for `Jane`/`Orange` either `Alpha1` or `Beta2` could be "first" as there is no `ORDER BY` clause that specifies which of the two should be first.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YzJtJxde)